# GCM Notification crashes app after I close the app

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

When my app is running (in the foreground and background), I can receive notifications, and show the notifications to the user using Android's `NotificationManager`. However, after sliding the app away from recents, when the app receives a notification, I get the message `Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped working`.

I know the app should be able to receive notifications after swiping it away from recents, because I have already set up Baidu Notifications, and I am able to receive them after swiping away the app. But with GCM, it just causes the app to crash. Here is the code in question:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.my.pkg.MyGcmReceiver", Exported = true, Permission = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" }, Categories = new string[] { "com.my.pkg" })]
public class MyGcmReceiver : GcmReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnReceive(context, intent);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MyGcmReceiver - OnReceive called &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
        CreateNotification();
    }

    private void CreateNotification()
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);

        builder.SetAutoCancel(true);
        builder.SetDefaults(NotificationCompat.DefaultAll);
        builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);
        builder.SetContentTitle("HI");
        builder.SetContentText("MSG FROM GCM");
        builder.SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);

        manager.Notify(0, builder.Build());
    }
}
```

By commenting out the line `CreateNotification();` in the `OnReceive` method, the app won't crash, but of course then it doesn't create and show the notification.

Comment: Any reason why you're using Google Cloud Messaging and not Firebase Could Messaging?

Comment: @MadhavShenoy I was writing the same.

Comment: :D With FCM you dont need to write code for handling notifications

Comment: @MadhavShenoy Yes, I am using Xamarin Forms, which uses Android.Support.* 23.3.0, while FCM relies on Android.Support.* 25.1.0, so until Xamarin Forms is updated, I need to use GCM

Comment: I've used FCM with Xamarin forms app. I'll tell you the versions I use

Comment: @MadhavShenoy really? I'm interested to know. I'd prefer to use FCM over GCM

Comment: @sme, I think you're right, I just checked the latest version of xamarin forms, still doesn't reach android support 25.1.0, so wondering how can it be used in xamarin forms app.

Comment: And also, have you tried to debug this code? What is the exception?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT , I'm not sure how to debug it, as it only happens when the app is closed. Though I managed to fix the issue, by moving the CreateNotification() code from MyGcmReceiver.OnReceive() method to GcmListenerService.OnMessageReceived() method (I had to create my own class that inherited GcmListenerService, in order to override OnMessageReceived). Now I am able to receive notifications, even after the app is swiped away from recents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comment, using FCM seems a lot easier, since it takes care of handling the message.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin Forms Version 2.3.224(It should also work with 2.3.3.193). I'm also attaching a screenshot of the Nuget packages in my solution. I added Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging to the Android Project not the forms project.[image]

To run FCM, you'll have to create an account and download the google-services.json file. More on this [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

To implement this in Xamarin Forms I created 2 services in Android, 
1 a dependency service 
2 an intent service.

The dependency service just checks if PlayService is available and fetch the FirebaseToken.

```
    public class PlayServices: IPlayService
{
    public string IsPlayServicesAvailable()
    {
        int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Forms.Context);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.Success)
        {
            if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsUserResolvableError(resultCode))
                return GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorString(resultCode);
            return "This device is not supported";
        }
        return "Available";
    }

    public string FirebaseToken => FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
}
```

Now, w.r.t. the IntentService

```
    [Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseIidService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
    {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }

}
```

This will run as soon as the App starts and generally completes in about 6-7 seconds after the app has started. This generates a token from Firebase and gives it to the app.

Although you don't need the token (since you can send push messages to all phones which have installed your app), you can use it to send push notifications just to this Phone only.

Hope this helps

Comment: What is the version of Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging package? I tried to install latest stable version 42.1001.0 to android project, but it suggests that a dependent package is failed to be installed and when I compile the project, there are 20 warnings and 9 errors.

Comment: Interesting, I clean up the solution and rebuild it, works fine now...Yet everytime I tried to install messaging package to a new forms project, the same errors would occur, and I never tried to clean and rebuild it, that's why I thought FCM cannot be used with xamarin forms... Thanks anyway.